# Restrict users without an academic address (.co.uk).

Tags: node.js

I am doing website. And it require user to register with email. And it should restrict users without an academic address (.co.uk).

How can i achieve that?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Just check if the email string they supply ends with .co.uk?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: fwiw, `.co.uk` is not specific generally associated with academia, although not exclusively, `.co` subdomain were intended for commercial use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a register route

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email
  if (!email.endsWith('.co.uk')) {
    // don't accept this email for registration
  }
})
```